# Embedding quantum affine algebras at different levels

Tags: quantum-groups

For $l$ a positive integer, an affine Lie algebra
$\widehat{\mathfrak{g}}$ has a level $l$ embedding $\phi_l: \widehat{\mathfrak{g}} \longrightarrow \widehat{\mathfrak{g}}$ which takes $x\otimes t^k$ to $x\otimes t^{kl}$ and multiplies the central extension by $l$.  Can the map $\phi_l$ be deformed to a map of quantum affine algebras?

Comment: Tony, are you interested in this map as a map of algebras, or map
of Hopf algebras? If you want a map of Hopf algebras, then I pretty
sure that I can prove it doesn't exist.

Comment:  Good question. I suppose I am interested in a map of Hopf algebras, so that would answer it. (I'm slightly confused because I'm thinking of the quantum affine Lie algebra in Drinfeld's new realization rather than the Kac-Moody realization, and I don't know what the coproduct is from this point of view.) On the other hand, if one starts with an embedding $\mathfrak{g}_1\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}_2$, then perhaps the induced map of affinizations does deform to a map of quantum affine algebras (as Hopf algebras).